# How to make option argument parsing in python?

Tags: python

I have

```
fruits = [ apple, banana , pineapple, oranges]
size = [ small, medium, large]
fruitproperties = [ color, weight]
```

My script aims to create txt files for fruitproperties of all fruit and size combinations. 
Currently I take main-directory as argument from command line. And compile outputs for all combinations.

Following is my code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Maindirectory required')
parser.add_argument('maindir' help = ' give maindir path', action = 'store')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

I want to make it as follow:

```
maindir is compulsory argument 
fruit name is optional argument
```

like

```
file.py <maindirpath>
```

will compile for all targets

and when `file.py <maindirpath> -p fruitname` is given
it will compile only for that fruit. 
for all of its combinations
for example:

```
apple-small, apple-medium and apple-large.
```

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: currently I take only maindir as argument and compile for all combinations. I also want to add a feature so that user will specify fruit name and it will compile for all combinations for that fruit. if user does not specify it will compile for all fruits. the user in case should give file.py <maindirpath> -p fruitname

Comment: I am new to python. don't know how to make argument parsing optional.

Answer (score 1):

You can add optional elements to your [`ArgumentParser`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html#combining-positional-and-optional-arguments)

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Maindirectory required')
parser.add_argument('maindir', help = ' give maindir path', action = 'store')
parser.add_argument("-p", "--printfruit", help="print specific fruit", type=str)
args = parser.parse_args() 
print args.maindir
print args.printfruit
```

Some examples:

- Requires at least `maindir`

  ```
  >python test.py
  usage: test.py [-h] [-p PRINTFRUIT] maindir
  test.py: error: too few arguments
  ```
- Providing `maindir`

  ```
  >python test.py C:\Fruits
  C:\Fruits
  None
  ```
- Providing both `maindir` and the optional value

  ```
  >python test.py C:\Fruits -p apple
  C:\Fruits
  apple
  ```

---

If I am understanding your comment correctly, you are looking to default some arguments if they are not present. You can provide the `default` argument, and a little manipulation to make it a list:

```
parser.add_argument("-p", "--printfruit", help="print specific fruit", type=str, default="apple, pineapple, banana")
args = parser.parse_args() 
fruit = [str(item) for item in args.printfruit.split(',')]
```

Now, use the `fruit` variable, instead of `args.printfruit` in the rest of your program.

Outputs:

- Without a fruit

  ```
  >python test.py C:\Fruits
  C:\Fruits
  apple, pineapple, banana            # This is args.printfruit
  ['apple', ' pineapple', ' banana']  # This is the fruits variable
  ```
- With a fruit value

  ```
  >python test.py C:\Fruits -p apple
  C:\Fruits
  apple        # This is args.printfruit
  ['apple']    # This is the fruits variable
  ```

Comment: Thanks for this. so basically this is my optional argument and second one. sys.argv[2]. and my remaining code will make use of it. So how can I write it that if this optional argument is present , do fruit = sys.argv[2] else fruits = [apple, pineapple, banana]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Yes I wanted the same. I just have one doubt. Currently I make maindir = sys.argv[1] { this is my compulsory argument- maindirectory} and now fruit = sys.argv[2]. Now the case is: if optional argument is not present, then my code will make use of only maindir. But sometimes optional argument will be given, if that case I have to make it fruit = sys.argv[2]. and use it. How can I add this condition in the code? that if optional argument is given then fruit = sys.argv[2] else fruits = [apple, banana, pineapple]

Comment: Check if `sys.argv[2]` is `None`. If it is not, set `fruit` to the passed value, otherwise default it to your list. Alternatively, wrap a `try/except` around just assigning `fruit = sys.argv[2]` and if you catch an `IndexError`, you didn't get a passed value and assign your `fruit` to the default.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using [`docopt`](http://docopt.org/), configure your option parser with a human-readable docstring:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8
"""Print Fruit permutations.

Usage:
    fruit.py <maindirpath> [--printfruit=<fruit>...]
    fruit.py --help

Arguments:
    <maindirpath>  Base directory to create files in

Options:
    -p, --printfruit=<fruit>  specify fruit to print
    -h, --help                display this help and exit
"""

from docopt import docopt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = docopt(__doc__)
    print(args)
```

---

`docopt` checks for syntactical correctness and returns given options in a dictionary:

```
$ ./fruit.py
Usage:
    fruit.py <maindirpath> [--printfruit=<fruit>...]
    fruit.py --help

$ ./fruit.py foobar
{'--help': False,
 '--printfruit': [],
 '<maindirpath>': 'foobar'}

$ ./fruit.py foobar -p apple -p banana
{'--help': False,
 '--printfruit': ['apple', 'banana'],
 '<maindirpath>': 'foobar'}
```